# Enable notification channels programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-notifications, android-8.0-oreo, android-settings

I am able to check if the channel is enabled/disabled with

```
NotificationChannel channel = manager.getNotificationChannel(channelId);
boolean isEnabled = channel.getImportance() != IMPORTANCE_NONE;
```

But if the channel is not enabled then I would like to enable it by setting it to IMPORTANCE_HIGH

```
if (!isEnabled) {
channel.setImportance(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
}
```

The problem is that the channel is not updated, it only works if I tried to disable it with IMPORTANCE_NONE in case it is enabled, but not the way around.

I have tried to delete the channel and create a new one with a different id, that works, but not creating a new one with the same id.

How to get around this?

Comment: If channel can enable/disable by third party app . Then what's the use case of having a channel ? You can not change the channel priority.

Comment: You might only be able to manipulate your own app's channels. Not the other apps. It looks like it is possible to disable them programatically, setting the importance to NONE

Answer (score 3):

You can't change channel importance programmatically without deleting the channel.

Because user may have changed the importance manually.

To achieve this programmatically to get channel and create new channel with new id.
delete the old channel.
 **Your changes will not reflect if create channel with previous id**

for reference check WhatsApp application try to change the ringtone from application and see in channel at bottom left *x channel is deleted message*

Answer (score 0):

When a notification channel is disabled, all you can do is ask the user to enable it. You can navigate the user directly to the channel settings screen.

```
fun openNotificationChannelSettings(context: Context, channelId: String) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_CHANNEL_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS)
        intent.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_APP_PACKAGE, context.packageName)
        intent.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_CHANNEL_ID, channelId)
        context.startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```